# SharePoint and Enterprise Library 4.0

Tags: oracle, sharepoint, enterprise-library

Has anybody been successful in integrating the Enterprise Library v4.0 with SharePoint WSS 3.0?  I created a very simple .ASPX page.  It's only purpose will to be to connect to an Oracle database and display some values in a DropDownList.  But right now, all it does is displays Hello World.  I've added the necessary references and everything compiles fine.  When I test the page, it displays Hello World.  But once I add the using Microsoft.Practices.EnterprisesLibrary.Data, the page no longer works. I just get the standard Unknown Error message.  Is there a log file I can check?

I'm looking for any steps or tips that I can use to get this up and running.  I use this Enterprise Library in all my ASP.NET applications and it works great.  Trying to get this to work in SharePoint seems like a natural fit.  But why does it seem so difficult?  And why does there seem to be a lack of information?

Anyways, thank you so much for any information anybody can provide.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the Enterprise Library, but to get a more meaningful error message from SharePoint than the super informative "Unknown Error" message go modify a couple things in web.config:

1. In `<SharePoint><SafeMode>` set the CallStack property = "true"
2. In `<system.web><compilation>` set the debug property = "true"
3. In `<system.web><customErrors>` set the mode property = "Off"

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to debug and see where the failure is occurring in your code?  Is it occurring on an Enterprise Library related call?  If so I would capture the exception that is being thrown and evaluate the message that it provides using; try {} catch (Exception ex) {}.

One thing I have seen with Enterprise Library that if it is not properly configured it will sometimes log messages to the Event Log on the server.

I'm sorry I can't get much more information without more technical details about your implementation.  I can assure you though that Enterprise Library works very well with SharePoint and that for the past few years I have used Enterprise Library in all of my SharePoint solution work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add the EntLib assemblies to the GAC and add them to the SafeControls section of your application's web.config...

Answer (score 0):

Follow up: the app I'm working on has it's own web.config file.  I'm not sure if this is right or wrong.  I've read where I should link the WSS web.config to my application and delete the one in my app folder.  I tried that and when I did, I got an error message I've never seen.

So, I added the following to my local web.config

```
    <add assembly="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
```

and the error above disappears.  My preference would be to use the web.config from WSS.  I'm going to keep working on it and hope to find something that works so I can share.